# Eclipse for Mac OS 10.4

Tags: eclipse, macos

Does anyone know where I can get Eclipse for Mac OS 10.4?

I have tried downloading versions that say "10.4 or later" but whenever I run it it tells me I need 10.5. Has anyone else this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse 3.5 should run on 10.4, I'm sure I remember doing this myself late in the 3.5 release cycle.  Be sure you get the Carbon download, Cocoa does require 10.5.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs to know, download the Carbon versions of Eclipse to work in 10.4. Thanks to all that helped. :)